# How to know where warning come from in Python

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

Is it possible to display line number along with warnings? I'm getting some warnings, possibly from numpy, but I have no idea where they come from. I don't want my code to aboard or to raise an exception, but I'd like to get more information from the origin of the warnings. Is it something possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warnings that are issued via the `warnings` module are by default printed including file name and line number, and the output can be controlled by the functions in the `warnings` module as well as by the `-W` parameter to the Python interpreter.  Since your warnings apparently don't include file name and line number, the `warnings` module probably won't help you.  Since you suspect that `numpy` might be the culprit, I suggest having a look at the [`numpy.seterr()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generate/numpy.seterr.html) function.  Maybe turning warnings into errors helps.

Answer (score 2):

Write a separate module like this.

```
import warnings

# capture all warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warns:
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    # do the stuff that triggers warnings.  i.e. import your main module
    # and call whatever is necessary to get it going.  This must all be
    # indented under the with statement!

# afterward, print captured warnings
for w in warns:
    print w.category.__name__, "(%s)" % w.message,
    print "in", w.filename, "at line", w.lineno
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT:*

Arg! I inexplicably got the name wrong.

Use the pychecker module. If you have distutils installed, then just type: `easy_install pychecker` on the command line to get the newest version. By default in generates warnings, and lists the line numbers for them.

Comment: @Charles Brunet Sorry about that. I mixed the names of my modules up. It's actually pychecker. And it can go into your called modules if necessary, so it could check numpy for you.

Comment: pychecker analyse source, it does nothing about runtime errors and warnings.